# Query related tables in Android without using rawQuery()

Tags: android, database, sqlite

When I have to query related tables I always use a `rawQuery()`. However, is there a better approach without raw queries neither ContentProviders?
It is very painful to write the raw queries if you have definied all the fields as constants (not hardcoded) and you have to concat all of them by hand. It is very easy to make mistakes.
Thanks!

Here you have some simplified code example, as you can see, it is not "polite" to concat the constants all the time...

```
String sql = "SELECT "+T_PARTICIPATION+".* , "+STUDENT_SURNAME+"+\", \"+"+NAME+" AS "+NAME+" "+
        "FROM "+T_PARTICIPATION+", "+T_STUDENT+" "+
        "WHERE "+T_PARTICIPATION+"."+CONNECTION_PROFILE_ID+"=1 AND "+SEANCE_ID+" IN (1, 2)";
return mDatabase.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

**Edit:** While no more answers are provided, I accept the one provided by @JoeMalin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that this is an SQLite database that doesn't need to be exposed as a content provider, so keeping it as SQLite is the right approach.

Why don't you use SQLiteDatabase.query()? It allows a selection string and an array of
selection arguments. Or, what you may need is SQLiteQueryBuilder. Without knowing more about your app, or seeing your current code, it's hard to say.

Comment: Hi! Yes, this does not need to be exposed as a content provider. I do not use query() as it does not allow you to query multiple tables (that is multiple tables in FROM). I have edited the question and included some code. From your response, I think that this method in SQLiteQueryBuilder is the more appropiate: `public static String buildQueryString (boolean distinct, String tables, String[] columns, String where, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)
`

Comment: Do you know if there is any better way to do that than using `buildQueryString()`?